# What is the difference betweeen %INC and @INC?

Tags: perl, arrays, perlvar

What is the difference between `%INC` and `@INC` in Perl?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [@INC](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@INC) array holds all the file system paths where Perl will be looking for modules when you use or require them.

After use or require, the [%INC](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%INC) hash will contain the loaded modules and where they were loaded from.

Examples from my laptop:

@INC:

```
'/etc/perl',
'/usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.0',
'/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.0',
'/usr/lib/perl5',
'/usr/share/perl5',
'/usr/lib/perl/5.10',
'/usr/share/perl/5.10',
'/usr/local/lib/site_perl',
'.'
```

and %INC:

```
'warnings/register.pm' => '/usr/share/perl/5.10/warnings/register.pm',
'bytes.pm' => '/usr/share/perl/5.10/bytes.pm',
'XSLoader.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl/5.10/XSLoader.pm',
'Carp.pm' => '/usr/share/perl/5.10/Carp.pm',
'Exporter.pm' => '/usr/share/perl/5.10/Exporter.pm',
'warnings.pm' => '/usr/share/perl/5.10/warnings.pm',
'overload.pm' => '/usr/share/perl/5.10/overload.pm',
'Data/Dumper.pm' => '/usr/lib/perl/5.10/Data/Dumper.pm'
```

(%INC contains Data::Dumper because I used it to quickly dump those two values).

Answer (score 6):

See [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for `@INC`, `%INC` and all other special variables in Perl.

Answer (score 2):

http://perl.apache.org/docs/general/perl_reference/perl_reference.html#The__INC_array